# Refresh Deutsche Bank API access token

Tags: api, token, refresh, banking

I am following the instructions on how to refresh the access token of the Deutsche Bank API.
[You can find the instructions following this link.](https://developer.db.com/apidocumentation/oauthflows/oauthrefreshgrant) I am using Postman and tried a lot of different things (headers, authorization type etc.) but so far I have not been able to refresh the token.
Has someone been working with the Deutsche Bank API and/or knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you resolved your problem, but I had the same issue - you have to add client_id and client_secret to your request (it seems, that the documentation is not complete).